# Shift one entry in table to the right

Tags: tables, tabularx

How do shift one entry (the letter T) to the extreme right of the cell? Here is my code.

```
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  T & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Tried to google for a function `\shift_to_right{T}` but it doesnt exist.

Comment: edited to make it simple

Comment: Replace `T` by `\multicolumn{1}{r}{T}`? Of course, in this simple example this does not really have a big impact, but if you replace the entry `4` below the `T` by `444444` you will see that it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *must* be a duplicate of something, but you can always change the alignment of a single cell with `\multicolumn{1}{<alignment>}{<content>}`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{T} & 2 & 3 \\
  4444444 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `T` is at the very right of its cell.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  \hfill T & 2 & 3 \\
  444444   & 5 & 6 \\
         7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```